# Add support for images to Twitter oneboxing

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, twitter

When you do a Twitter onebox, it embeds the twitter text nicely.  However, if the tweet is mostly for the sake of sharing an image, that text isn't really useful, and you then need to click the link in the tweet to view the image.  This kinda undermines the point of oneboxing.

Can embedded images get added to Twitter oneboxes?